# My ARRAY is into a OBJECT; how I can print a VALUE of this ARRAY?

Tags: arrays

I have just this var of name "$Q" and this is a object.
Also into my object I have a array.
¿how I can take just the VALUE of key[0] or KEY[1] ???

Thanks.

This is my data:

```
    var_dump($Q);
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["fecha_de_registro"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2015-10-31"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "18:25:58"
  }
}

    var_dump($Q -> $kt[2]);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2015-10-31"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "18:25:58"
}

    print_r($Q -> $kt[2]);
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-10-31
    [1] => 18:25:58
)


    print_r($Q -> $kt[2][1]);
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$e in <b>C:HTTPWWWacceso.php</b> on line <b>149</b><br />
```

Comment: What language is this? Javascript? PHP? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

$Q->fetcha_de_registro[0] would access element 0 and $Q->fetcha_de_registro[1] would access element 1.

Comment: Thanks but I need used the value of my var:

 "$kt[2]"

I need used this "dynamic name".

Comment: $Q->kt will fetch the entire kt array.  So if you store $myKt = $Q->kt you can access as myKt like you would any array which is equal to direct access like this: $Q->kt.  Then you access the individual element with $Q->kt[2] or $myKt[2] with variable.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is PHP, It seems your array has sub array as well, you could print it this simple way.

```
    foreach($Q as $key => $value) {
       print_r($value);
       foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
           print_r($subvalue);
       }
    }
```